# How to export a table that has a sub-column to an Excel file?

Tags: c#, export-to-excel

I have a table with a column, A.  In column A there are 2 sub-columns, A1 and A2. How can I export the table to an Excel file using C#?

Comment: we need a lot more informaton about the table.  Is it a datatable object?  Are you using a database? Whats up

Comment: What table is it? HTML table, Table object? Be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about Data grid view you can do like this:

```
   public void ExportToExecl(DataGridView dg, string filename)
    {
         // creating Excel Application
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        // creating new WorkBook within Excel application
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
        // creating new Excelsheet in workbook
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet worksheet = null;
        // get the reference of first sheet. By default its name is Sheet1.
        // store its reference to worksheet
        try
        {
            worksheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Sheets["Sheet1"];
            worksheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)workbook.ActiveSheet;
            // changing the name of active sheet
            worksheet.Name = "Exported from History Parsing";
            // storing header part in Excel
            for (int i = 1; i < dg.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
            {
                worksheet.Cells[1, i] = dg.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;
                worksheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Gray);
            }
            // storing Each row and column value to excel sheet
            for (int i = 0; i < dg.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < dg.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    worksheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = dg.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
                    worksheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Gray);
                }
            }
            // save the application
            workbook.SaveAs(filename, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
            MessageBox.Show("Your excel file was created successfully");
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            app.Quit();
            workbook = null;
            app = null;
        }
    }
```

You also can read about export dgv to excel here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28269/Exporting-a-DataGridView-to-an-Excel-PDF-image-fil

and here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43400/Generalized-DataGridView-Export-to-Excel-with-Them

- Before you write code, you must add a reference to the Microsoft Excel object library. 
  Right click on your project and select Add Reference menu. After that go to COM tab and select and add Microsoft Excel 12.0 object library